# Why Stacking rasters return all values as NAs?

Tags: raster, r

I have several rasters that I want to do some calculations ,basically calculating the moving average.

```
    saf
   class       : RasterStack 
   dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1036800, 601  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
   resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
   extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

I am gratful to anyhelp

Comment: Have you calculated statistics on your output (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m3000000)?  Sometimes you need to do this manually before you can get sensible summaries.

Comment: why are you doing 2 times stack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NA's here refer to the fact that the min and max value are unknown (this is no longer the case in the current version of 'raster'). Your function should work if you use 'calc' instead of 'overlay'